# UIPickerView starting value

Tags: objective-c, ios, uipickerview

Here is where i specify how many rows uipicker should have

```
   - (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
        NSUInteger numRows = 15;

        return numRows;
    }
```

With that implementation pickers gives option for choose from 0 to 14. What to do so the picker to show the values from 2 to 14 (not to show 0, 1 and 2) ?

//EDIT

```
self.totalPlayers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:2],
                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:3],
                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:4],
                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:5],
                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:6],
                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:7],
                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:8],
                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:9],
                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:10],
                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:11],
                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:12],
                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:13],
                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:14],
                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:15],
                    nil];
```

Comment: i think its working as expected after your edited code. please re-check

Answer (score 0):

The ideal way to do this would be to use an Array.

instead of returning hardcoded length of 15, return array count

Make changes in the array to leave out 0,1,2 or any particular row for that matter.